# UPDATE with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join, javadb

I'm using JavaDB and working with two tables in the same database.

I'm trying to update the PrevSales column in the "SalesResp" table with the values that are in the "SellDate" column of the "Vehicles" table when the Vehicle table's SellDate is before a the specified date. I'm matching the data between the two tables by using the "VIN" column that is present in both tables.

I continually get errors surrounding the inner join in my code, SQL state 42x01.

```
UPDATE SALESRESP JOIN VEHICLES ON (SALESRESP.VIN = VEHICLES.VIN) 
SET SALESRESP.PrevSale = VEHICLES.SELLDATE WHERE 
(((VEHICLES.SELLDATE)<'2013-09-24'));
```

I've tried various configurations, swapping the INNER JOIN and the SET placements, I've tried including a "FROM" clause. Nothing seems to work. Any advice?

EDIT: Exact Error Code:

```
Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "JOIN" at line 1, column 19.
```

Comment: Please show the error you are getting. Also, I don't think you have to use INNER, Join should be sufficient.

Comment: Edited it. Also tried it without the "INNER" and it still fussed about the existence of the word "JOIN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and see, replace your date instead of sysdate.

```
UPDATE SALESRESP  
SET SALESRESP.PrevSale  = (SELECT VEHICLES.SELLDATE FROM VEHICLES 
WHERE SALESRESP.VIN = VEHICLES.VIN  AND
VEHICLES.SELLDATE <'2013-09-24');
```

Comment: Is a join not necessary? I thought I needed one when working with two different tables?
EDIT: tried it and got an error again:
  Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 61.

Comment: Join keyword is really not necessary. There are ways which you can simulate the joins using the conditions inside the where statement. does the above code work for you?

Comment: Ah okay, good to know about the joins. But it still isn't working for me. Same error code, only this time with the "FROM" Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 61.

Comment: I added a select in like you recommended and it works but doesn't grab the correct dates. So close but no cigar just yet :\

Comment: I reset the connections today and this ended up working! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE S SET S.PrevSale = V.SELLDATE FROM SALESRESP S 
inner join  VEHICLES V on S.VIN = V.VIN AND V.SELLDATE < '2013-09-24'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try being more explicit:

`UPDATE SALESRESP 
    SET SALESRESP.PrevSale = VEHICLES.SELLDATE 
    FROM VEHICLES
        JOIN SALESREP ON (SALESRESP.VIN = VEHICLES.VIN) 
        WHERE (((VEHICLES.SELLDATE)<'2013-09-24'))`

See if that will work.

Comment: It gives me the error: "Error code 30000, SQL state 42X03: Column name 'VEHICLES.SELLDATE' is in more than one table in the FROM list." I tried adding a few more () to try to separate it out more, but it didn't like that either.

Comment: Sorry forgot to change the JOIN reference see change above.

Comment: It is still carrying on about "vehicles.selldate" being a column in more then one table. But thanks for the help!