# Update a table by using multiple joins

Tags: sql-update, inner-join, multiple-tables, javadb

I am using Java DB (Java DB is Oracle's supported version of Apache Derby and contains the same binaries as Apache Derby. source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/faqs-jsp-156714.html#1q2).

I am trying to update a column in one table, however I need to join that table with 2 other tables within the same database to get accurate results (not my design, nor my choice).

Below are my three tables, ADSID is a key linking Vehicles and Customers and ADDRESS and ZIP in Salesresp are used to link it to Customers. (Other fields left out for the sake of brevity.)

Salesresp(address, zip, prevsale)

Customers(adsid, address, zipcode)

Vehicles(adsid, selldate)

The goal is to find customers in the SalesResp table that have previously purchased a vehicle before the given date. They are identified by address and adsid in Customers and Vechiles respectively.

I have seen updates to a column with a single join and in fact asked a question about one of my own update/joins here ([UPDATE with INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218921/update-with-inner-join)). But now I need to take it that one step further and use both tables to get all the information.

I can get a multi-JOIN SELECT statement to work:

```
SELECT * FROM salesresp 
INNER JOIN  customers ON (SALESRESP.ZIP = customers.ZIPCODE) AND 
(SALESRESP.ADDRESS = customers.ADDRESS)
INNER JOIN vehicles  ON (Vehicles.ADSId =Customers.ADSId ) 
WHERE (VEHICLES.SELLDATE<'2013-09-24');
```

However I cannot get a multi-JOIN UPDATE statement to work.

I have attempted to try the update like this:

```
UPDATE salesresp SET PREVSALE = (SELECT SALESRESP.address FROM SALESRESP
WHERE SALESRESP.address IN (SELECT customers.address FROM customers 
WHERE customers.adsid IN (SELECT vehicles.adsid FROM vehicles 
WHERE vehicles.SELLDATE < '2013-09-24')));
```

And I am given this error: "Error code 30000, SQL state 21000: Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row".

But if I change that first "=" to a "IN" it gives me a syntax error for having encountered "IN" (Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01).

I also attempted to do more blatant inner joins, but upon attempting to execute this code I got the the same error as above: "Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01" with it complaining about my use of the "FROM" keyword.

```
update salesresp set prevsale = vehicles.selldate
from salesresp sr
inner join vehicles v
on sr.prevsale = v.selldate
inner join customers c
on v.adsid = c.adsid 
where v.selldate < '2013-09-24';
```

And in a different configuration:

```
update salesresp
inner join customer on salesresp.address = customer.address
inner join vehicles on customer.adsid = vehicles.ADSID
set salesresp.SELLDATE = vehicles.selldate where vehicles.selldate < '2013-09-24';
```

Where it finds the "INNER" distasteful: Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "inner" at line 3, column 1.

What do I need to do to get this multi-join update query to work? Or is it simply not possible with this database?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would:

1) Turn off autocommit (if you haven't already)

2) Craft a select/join which returns a set of columns that identifies the record you want to update E.g. select c1, c2, ... from A join B join C... WHERE ...

3) Issue the update. E.g. update salesrep SET CX = cx where C1 = c1 AND C2 = c2 AND...
(Having an index on C1, C2, ...  will boost performance)

4) Commit.

That way you don't have worry about mixing the update and the join, and doing it within a txn ensures that nothing can change the result of the join before your update goes through.